# Decide user that can publish a post

Tags: posts, publish

I have the users that can send posts as pending for admin approval.

Is it possibile to have that the user that add this post (as custom type) may choose another user that can publish that post?

Comment: Any user that has a role of `Editor` can publish the post. I don't think it can be restricted down to one user nor can those permissions be granted on a post-by-post basis to a non-Editor.

Comment: I don't want to allow an users that doesn't have privileges, but I want that user that create the post can choose an editor user (and just one) that can approved the post.